# replace lines in one file with lines in another by line number

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a fileA.txt with many lines and I want to replace specific lines with other specific lines from a second file fileB.txt which also has many lines

For example:
fileA.txt

```
Italy
Korea
USA
England
Peru
Japan
Uruguay
```

fileB.txt

```
Argentina
Switzerland
Spain
Greece
Denmark
Singapore
Thailand
Colombia
```

I want to replace line 2, 4, 5 and 7 in the first file with lines 1, 2, 5 and 8 from the second file:

Output:

```
Italy
Argentina
USA
Switzerland
Denmark
Japan
Colombia
```

I guess I can do it with awk or sed but if awk this code does not seems provide the information of the lines of the second file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$2]=$1; next }FNR in a{ $0=a[FNR] }1' fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's the logic behind 1/2, 4, 5, 7/8? You chose them randomly? If you want to script it, it implies you want to automate some larger job, but you haven't given me a feel for what the true problem is.

Comment: it is a bit complex to explain why I selected those, let's just say it random because I will have another pair of files and there the line numbers I will need to replace it is going to be different so I need a code where you input the line numbers that you want to substitute in the first file and the line numbers of the second file

Comment: so I just modify the same code where I input different values of line numbers every time

Comment: it would be good to have also two different files where the values of the line numbers are stored perhaps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v a='2,4,5,7' -v b='1,2,5,8' '
BEGIN { split(a, ax, ","); split(b, bx, ",");
        for(n in ax) mapping[ bx[n] ] =ax[n];
};
NR==FNR { if (FNR in mapping) hold[ mapping[FNR] ]=$0; next; };
{ print (FNR in hold)? hold[FNR]: $0; }' fileB fileA
```

Here, we pass line numbers as an *awk* `-v`ariable in `a='...'` (for fileA) and `b='...'` (for fileB), then we [`split()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) them into an array on comma character as the separator (note that `a` and `b` were variables, while now `ax` and `bx` are arrays).

then we build a another `mapping` array from `ax` and `bx` arrays to map the lines which those should be replaced in fileA with the ones from fileB;

now keys (or indexes) of the *`mapping`* array is line numbers of the fileB and the values of these keys are the line numbers of the fileA, as below:

the `mapping` array is:

```
Key    Value
1      2
2      4
5      5
8      7
```

so now what we need, that is, just to read the line numbers from fileB that match with the keys above (FNRs of `1`, `2`, `5` and `8`), so we do that with:

```
NR==FNR { if (FNR in mapping) hold[ mapping[FNR] ]=$0; next; };
```

OK, now what is the value of the `mapping[FNR]`? if you check the `mapping` array above, that would be:

```
mapping[1] --> 2; then-we-have    hold[ mapping[1] ] --> hold[2]=$0
mapping[2] --> 4; then-we-have    hold[ mapping[2] ] --> hold[4]=$0
mapping[5] --> 5; then-we-have    hold[ mapping[5] ] --> hold[5]=$0
mapping[8] --> 7; then-we-have    hold[ mapping[8] ] --> hold[7]=$0
```

so we used the value of `mapping` array as the key for the `hold` array and `hold` array is now contains:

```
Key     Value
2       Argentina
4       Switzerland
5       Denmark
7       Colombia
```

now the last step is to use keys in `hold` array as the matched line number in fileA and replace that lines with the values of that key from the `hold` array if that line number found in the array or print the line itself if not found (Ternary operator: `condition? if-true : if-false`), and we do that with:

```
{ print (FNR in hold)? hold[FNR]: $0; }
```

Answer (score 5):

Using standard `sed`:

```
$ printf '%ds/^/%dc\\\\\\\n/p\n' 1 2 2 4 5 5 8 7 | sed -n -f /dev/stdin fileB | sed -f /dev/stdin fileA
Italy
Argentina
USA
Switzerland
Denmark
Japan
Colombia
```

The command pipeline,

```bsh
printf '%ds/^/%dc\\\\\\\n/p\n' 1 2 2 4 5 5 8 7 |
sed -n -f /dev/stdin fileB |
sed -f /dev/stdin fileA
```

first generates a `sed` substitute statement for each pair of line numbers using `printf`.  The output of the `printf` call is the following `sed` script:

```
1s/^/2c\\\
/p
2s/^/4c\\\
/p
5s/^/5c\\\
/p
8s/^/7c\\\
/p
```

This `sed` script acts on line 1, 2, 5, and 8, and inserts `nc\` followed by a literal newline (for some line number `n`) at the start of the affected lines.

Running this across `fileB` (with `sed -n`) generates a new `sed` script:

```
2c\
Argentina
4c\
Switzerland
5c\
Denmark
7c\
Colombia
```

The `c` command replaces a line with the text following the `\`, so the script will replace lines 2, 4, 5, and 7.

Applying this to `fileA` generates the result.

Reading the line numbers from a file in which the first column contains line numbers for `fileB`, and the second column contains line numbers for `fileA`:

```
$ cat number-pairs
1 2
2 4
5 5
8 7
```

```
$ awk '{ printf "%ds/^/%dc\\\\\\\n/p\n", $1, $2 }' number-pairs | sed -n -f /dev/stdin fileB | sed -f /dev/stdin fileA
Italy
Argentina
USA
Switzerland
Denmark
Japan
Colombia
```

You may obviously swap `$1` and `$2` in he `awk` expression if you want to store the columns in the opposite order.